# Boolean attribute in record type, and use the record type in pipelined function

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
 CREATE or replace PACKAGE pipelined_pkg AS

     TYPE emp_rt IS RECORD
     ( empno    NUMBER(4)
     , ename    VARCHAR2(10)
     , job      VARCHAR2(9)
     , mgr      NUMBER(4)
     , hiredate DATE
     , sal      NUMBER(7,2)
     , comm     NUMBER(7,2)
     , deptno   number(2)
     , presntStatus   Boolean default false
     );

     TYPE emp_ntt IS TABLE OF pipelined_pkg.emp_rt;

     function pipelined_emp
        RETURN pipelined_pkg.emp_ntt PIPELINED;

  end pipelined_pkg;
  /
```

When I try to compile the above code I am getting

```
[ Error(17,15): PLS-00630: pipelined functions must have a supported collection return type ]
```

If I remove the Boolean attribute, it is compling fine.

**Is it not possible to have a Boolean attribute in record type, and use the record type in pipelined function?**

Answer (score 1):

Because SQL has no data type equivalent to BOOLEAN, you cannot:

- Assign a BOOLEAN value to a database table column
- Select or fetch the value of a database table column into a BOOLEAN
  variable
- Use a BOOLEAN value in a SQL statement, SQL function, or PL/SQL
  function invoked from a SQL statement

You cannot pass a BOOLEAN value to the DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT or DBMS_OUTPUT.PUTLINE subprogram. To print a BOOLEAN value, use an IF or CASE statement to translate it 
to a character value (for information about these statements, see "Conditional Selection Statements").

Refer http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS348 for further info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, there are no BOOLEAN type in oracle when used to define a record/column.
For those specific field, we usually use a NUMBER(1) or CHAR(1).